# how to push json data in select input and edit

Tags: angularjs, json

I am developing mobile application with the help of Angular and Ionic.

My address data is coming like this :

```
var data =  [{"Address":"abcd","City":"Aromas","StateName":"CALIFORNIA","Country":"United States","ZipCode":"95004"}]
```

So i just push this data in

```
$scope.Add = data;
```

and showed in View

```
<div ng-repeat="demoData in Add">
<label class="item item-input"><input type="text" placeholder="Address" ng-model="demoData.Address" name="uStreetName" required="" autocomplete="off"/></label> 
<label class="item item-input"><input type="text" placeholder="City" ng-model="demoData.City" name="uCity" required="" autocomplete="off"/></label> 
<label class="item item-input item-select"><div class="input-label">&nbsp;</div><select ng-model="demoData.StateID" ng-options="stateL.StateID as stateL.StateName for stateL in StateList"><option value="" disabled hidden>State</option></select></label> 
<label class="item item-input item-select"><div class="input-label">&nbsp;</div><select ng-model="demoData.CountryID" ng-options="countryL.CountryID as countryL.Country for countryL in CountryList"><option value="" disabled hidden>Country</option></select></label> 
<label class="item item-input"><input type="text" placeholder="Zip" ng-model="demoData.ZipCode" name="uZip" required="" autocomplete="off"/></label>  
</div>
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="go(demoData)">Next</button>
```

I have drop down for country and state data like this :

```
CountryList :[{"CountryID":1,"Country":"United States"},{"CountryID":2,"Country":"Austria"},{"CountryID":3,"Country":"India"}] 
StateList :[{"StateID":1,"StateName":"ALASKA"},{"StateID":2,"StateName":"ALABAMA"},{"StateID":3,"StateName":"ARKANSAS"},{"StateID":4,"StateName":"AMERICAN SAMOA"}]
```

My question is that, In address the state and country that are coming from API I have to show that in select input box and the user can edit the same. User are permitted to select the state and country if needed.

revised: 
I am using the address API to get the address and i am auto populating the same. I want to auto populate in the select input but condition is that the user can reselect the state and country if needed.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. It looks like your code should work... If you're asking how to populate the list dynamically, all you need to do is modify `CountryList` and `StateList` once you retrieve the data from your API.

Comment: make it simple..
I am using the address API to get the address and i am auto populating the same. I wan to auto populate in the select input but condition is that the user can reselect the state and country if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the select inputs populated, but need the default value to be the one already saved against the user's address. The problem you have is that you're using `CountryID` and `StateID` as the values for the select options, but the country and state saved in the user's address are using `Country` and `StateName`.

You also need to modify the models used with the inputs, as you don't have StateID and CountryID in the data.

To fix this, change the select inputs to use the name as both the value and name, like so:

```
<select ng-model="demoData.StateName" ng-options="stateL.StateName as stateL.StateName for stateL in StateList">
    <option value="" disabled hidden>State</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="demoData.Country" ng-options="countryL.Country as countryL.Country for countryL in CountryList">
    <option value="" disabled hidden>Country</option>
</select>
```